# Should I cache real-time geolocation data, acquired with API calls, because of potential rate-limit issues?

Tags: php, ajax, curl, geolocation, rate-limiting

I've been tasked with implementing the real-time location of a vehicle on a map, on a publicly accessible website.

I can get the latitude and longitude data (I'm doing cURL requests for a JSON response) from an API, however this API has a rate-limit of five concurrent requests, which I'm thinking is going to be an issue, if API calls are made several times a minute (right now, every five seconds) from a potentially high amount of individual client-browsers. Right now, the API GET request is being done, over and over, by every visitor.

How could one get around this? Should I cache new geolocation data every five seconds with a CRON job to a local storage, and then serve visitors "new" cached data continuously via Ajax?